# MySQL: get maximum consecutive occurrence

Tags: mysql

Hi i have following table on mysql DB.

```
USER_ID SCORE
5   0
5   1
5   1
5   1
5   1
5   1
5   1
5   0
5   0
5   0
5   1
5   1
5   1
5   0
5   0
5   1
5   1
5   0
5   0
```

expected result in this data highest score is 6.

How i will get it?

Comment: How can we order the table to get the clusters of scores which appear in your example?

Comment: Hint: you need a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Explain your expected output. Do you want consecutive max occurrence?

Comment: I want highest streak score in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query might do the job done:

```
    SELECT
    MAX(max_occurence_tracker)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            IF (@prev = score ,@c := @c + 1,@c := 0 ) max_occurence_tracker,
            @prev := score
        FROM otable,(SELECT @prev := - 1 ,@c := 1) var
    ) t;
```

**Note:** I've used the table name as `otable`.

**Caution:** If you have primary key in your table then use an order by on that `primary key` field. Otherwise you might get random behavior.

Unable to add an `SQL FIDDLE.`
So here's some test data. You can check the query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `otable`;
CREATE TABLE `otable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('1', '5', '0');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('2', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('3', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('4', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('5', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('6', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('7', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('8', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO `otable` VALUES ('9', '5', '0');
```

Comment: Thanks man i got it. In this we need to add +1 it will give 7 when count is 8. Thanks once again cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the largest value:

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name
```

I saw now that your title says "Count highest occurrences". This might do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(MAX(column_name)) FROM table_name
```

IF you KNOW the highest value you can do like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE score=6
```